# How to detect IPV6 address change in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, winsock

I was looking for a way to detect the IPV6 address change using delphi 7 on Windows XP and above. For vista , there is a windows API i know.  I came across code that claimed to do the same on XP as well . Here is the code below :

```
uses  WinSock2 ; //

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: TSocket;
  wsaD: TWSADATA;
  BytesReturned: u_long;
  PtrA: Pointer;
  Buffer: array[0..20] of INTERFACE_INFO;
  ret: Integer;
begin
  try
    FillChar(wsaD, SizeOf(wsaD), #0);
    FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), #0);
    WSAStartup($0101, wsaD);                      // Start WinSock,You should normally check for errors here

    {Create a WSA Socket}
    // s := WSASocketA(AF_INET6,SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, nil, 0, 0);

    s := Socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP);         // Open a socket
    if (s = INVALID_SOCKET) then
      Exit;

    PtrA := @bytesReturned;
    //   Ret :=  WSAIoCtl(s, SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_CHANGE, @Buffer,1024, @Buffer, 1024, PtrA, nil, nil);
    Ret :=  WSAIoCtl(s, SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_QUERY, nil,0, @Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), PtrA, nil, nil);
    DebugLog('Ret Value = ' + SysErrorMessage(WSAGetLastError),0);
    if ret = 0 then
    begin
      // DebugLog('IP Address changed !',0);
      //Showmessage('Operation succeeded !')
    end
    else
    begin
      //DebugLog('No change found in IP Address',0);
      // showmessage(SysErrorMessage(WSAGetLastError));
    end;

    WSAcleanUp;
  except

  end;
end;
```

I get the error code as

> "An Invalid argument was supplied."

When i change the control code to SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_QUERY , the code works fine then .

Can anyone guide me on this ?

Comment: damn . this control code is only valid on Windows Vista and above. My efforts are wasted. Can i get something equivalent for Windows XP ?

Comment: @TLama : I tried your method , it still says "Invalid arguement"

Comment: MSDN docs state that SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_QUERY is valid for WIndows 2000 and higher (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Remko : Yes , but nothing is mentioned about "SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_CHANGE" . This link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570814(v=vs.85).aspx mentions it is for Vista and above

Comment: @CyprUS that same link also states that SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_QUERY is Vista+ Your link seem to refer to drivers...

Comment: I tried this : `WSAIoctl (< socket >,SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_CHANGE,nil,0,nil,PtrA,nil,nil)` . It still fails.

Comment: CyprUS, the control operation referred on this [`SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_CHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff570814(v=vs.85).aspx) page should be invoked by the `WskControlSocket` function, not by `WSAIoCtl`, but as @Remko says, it's something related to drivers, so I'll rather delete my first comment to not confuse the others. I couldn't find a different documentation for this operation though. Sorry for misleading.